# Accept more than one array type in Generic Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, types, ramda.js

I am using helper object to check types of variables. But i have faced a problem with types. I have a generic `array: <T, V>(val: V | T[]): val is T[] => R.is(Array, val)`. Using this approach i am trying to avoid using `any`. This generic works well until `val` can be, for example, `string[]` or `number[]`.
Example:

```
const a = (b: string[] | number[] | string ) => {
  is.array(b)
}
```

In this case generic captures only the first possible array type and checks it. I am attaching a link to codesandbox with the illustration of issue. Please, help

[image]

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/r-is-with-type-predicate-forked-9s12b6?file=/src/index.ts:441-506)

Comment: Why not `<T>(val: any): val is T[]`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you) But it this case we have a return type `val is unknown[]` instead of having `val is string[] | val is number[]`. Maybe there is an option with `extends`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Array.isArray` :

```js
function f(b: string[] | number[] | string) {
  if (Array.isArray(b)) {
    // b: string[] | number[]
  } else {
    // b: string
  }
};
```

Its declaration:

```js
function isArray(arg: any): arg is any[];
```

Own typeguard implementation:

```js
function isArray(arg: any): arg is any[] {
  return arg !== null && typeof arg === "object" && "length" in arg;
}
```

Rambda solution:

```js
function array(arg: any): arg is any[] {
  return R.is(Array, arg);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the asnwer) But by task i should use ramda(

Comment: I tried to show how typeguards work so you can do what you need on your own

Comment: Appended rambda solution

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I just want to know is it possible to do something like that `array: <T extends Array<any>, V>(val: T | V): val is T => R.is(Array, val)`. T should extend array types of V. Part with `Array<any>` is incorrect now)

Comment: So i need to get from V all array types

Comment: I don't understand why, but yes, you can: 

```typescript
type Single =
  | number
  | string
  | symbol
  | bigint
  | boolean
  | null
  | undefined
  | object;

function array<V extends Single, T extends Single[]>(arg: V | T): arg is T {
  return R.is(Array, arg);
}
```

Comment: Or maybe you need typescript typeof https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html