# How to fix types mismatch

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, types

I have constructed quite complicated generic type for function which checks types. The issue has raised with check for Array.

```
array: <T extends Extract<V, any[]>, V>(val: T | V): val is T
```

The function is used in many places in the project, but i have problem with the only one usage. As generic expects to get among input types one or more array types, it return `val is never` if there are not array types.

```
const func = (notices: Record<any, any>) => {
  if (!is.array(notices)) {
    return
  }

  notices.forEach((notice) => {
    console.log(notice)
  })
```

And in this place it has become a problem due to `notices` is typed as never and never has not `forEach`. I am not sure, but if there is any solution not to break existing logic, but to fix it in this place (preferably without `(notices as any[]).forEach`, but to fix generic).

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gSzQLngG8BYAKHgvlhigE8AeAFXhAA8MQVg14BRdmmAz0AagBoqKWgG0AugD4JI%20QAoAblAgFmAH3giAlAQ0QcPRmQC%20ZG6WTosAMwCuKMPAC88FSiQZsYCD48ABK4EgwwPRQUhIxtPIGnvJEZJQ4jt4AhLgAdNR0Pn4BQQZJJOTplHAYzjAoaZTWlRS%20-oFouY4RvFBgABYqRe0gSR4pFVWU9mhIECC5EEgA5sMlBo0UlhuklkA)

Comment: If this depends on ramda you should tag it as such; if not, please remove the dependency from your example code so that nobody needs to worry about ramda to answer your question.  That "Playground link" is a codesandbox link; [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) is the TS Playground.

Comment: @jcalz Sorry... Yes, i should use Ramda unfortunately( I have tagged now

Comment: Really?  It seems that you have a typing question, not an implementation question, and your type is `<T extends Extract<V, any[]>, V>(val: T | V): val is T` which doesn't depend at all on ramda.  If you really intend that someone need to know about ramda in order to fix your typing, then okay, but somehow I doubt it.

Comment: @jcalz I have meant that i should use this function. No to replace it in that place to `Array.isArray() `

Comment: But you're not asking about implementation *at all*.  I could replace your code with [this](https://tsplay.dev/NakD6W) and it seems you have the same question without depending on ramda.  Part of the idea of a [mre] is to only include code directly relevant to the problem you're having.

Comment: @jcalz Well, i get it. I'll remove unnecessary part)

Comment: Anyway, if I assume that ramda is not relevant, I'd say that the call signature `<T extends Extract<V, any[]>, V>(val: T | V): val is T` isn't going to be useful for inferring `T` and `V`.  The only reason I could imagine using that call signature is if you're going to specify `T` and `V` manually. My suggestion with the code as written would be to replace it `(val: any): x is any[]` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WzexEm).  If that works for you I can write up an answer explaining.  If not, please [edit] the code to show where it fails to meet your needs.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks a lot for your option, but i should fix it using generic. You can consider this as a little challenge) The code fails in place `notice.forEach` and i want to know if it is possible to change generic a little bit to return val is any, for example, if val is typed as never due to absence of array type in parameter

Comment: I do like challenges, but I need use cases here.  Please [edit] the code to show cases where you need generics.  The current version is unmotivated; [you cannot meaningfully infer `T` and `V` from a value of type `T | V`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47213#issuecomment-1004300645)...  at best you can infer one of them.

Comment: @jcalz The problem is that i understand that it is a little bit unmotivated to use generics here. And i understand your option. But i have to use generic in order not to lose type of input parameter. I just want to return `val is (string | number)[] ` for `val: boolean | string[] | number[]`, for example. I see that it is unmotivated from the point that it is typeguard but still.

Comment: No thanks!  I'm not a big fan of the "chat" feature here.  You can either [edit] to show use cases or someone else might be able to help you.  Good luck!

Comment: You've almost given a [mre] except it's in a comment and not edited into the question as I asked.  Still: as far as I know there isn't a way to do this, since `(string | number)[]` is not a narrowing of `string[] | number[]`.  You'll either get `never` or `string[] | number[]` depending on how you do the filtering.  But *why* do you want the incorrect `(string | number)[]` instead of the correct `string[] | number[]` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Updated answer

```
declare const is: {
  array: (val: unknown): val is unknown[]
}
```

This is the same thing being done with `Array.isArray`.

A stricter solution (with better type hinting than `Array.isArray`) is as follows:

```
declare const is: {
    // For types which are just array types
    array<T extends Array<unknown>>(val: T | unknown[]): val is T extends Array<infer B> ? B[] : unknown[];
    // For types which contain no array types
    array<T>(val: Exclude<T, Array<unknown>>): val is Exclude<T, Array<unknown>> & unknown[];
    // For types which may contain array types
    array<T>(val: T extends Extract<T, Array<infer B>> ? B[] : Exclude<T, Array<unknown>>): val is T extends Extract<T, Array<infer B>> ? B[] : never;
}
```

Playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gSzQLngG8BYAKHgvgHor4AxJGeDATwAcQ14B3AC2zC94sBACsArpmEwYUFs3acylabJYAeACrwQADwwgUwLgEEZc9eJQBrFEm4oAfI4AUANygQC2gD7wrtvYoANoAugCUBB4QOFzaegZGpuYa2CgAZiBMAEKO8AD88Nlh8AQBdg5hANzKlDT0jAocXHwCQiLwdliwak1K5JQ9Fpqu0QQAorqQ4qBaADTwZmqWNhVOjpHw0bHwk9OzmgtLFuVBzvAAZP6rQdW1FPUMTKzNPPyC8AC2coioGFBpVQ-F79FRDDQjdyebw6fSGYy7fSyMAYeaLFLqNKZHLnQrFUKlRH7EBo44aU4OZybba4eDxOFJREYZGow7o5ZYrJFXFFEoEFAgNxZGqkAC+ZDIyHQWHw10CDngAF54AAiFVkbDpeAuXAAOnBLjQ4XCRHu1FosopIVCZrQuvSjHGUEELmASryhHgovCZFFOggaAQJAGDwtZRuDltvolpClUgA5gQoCh5Mq1RqtTq7Qb48bTSHzfBE3K1mEzfH7Y7nbxXe6iF6fWL-YH8yp6sXkyxy-a2Gxo6RJagpCgCGT1JgYGl43llWXSJrtXqDSg88G27QR-AJ1O5yoUJWYE6XW7FR6zSo40gICBdRAkPHXeERSpvSK-SAA0GzfVNwKhTBv1oAABDA0AAWj0DgUQgmRGDNfd0l7fsyHSKwUWwVB4HSFwACMCG3FB4xKPwUHET4cKyYit2ZKd4BIsiKJgE010oBcs31FJcNXc9KBwg8jxrLhT3rb0eNDeA8OoydCKo0jyMom0C3fT9WxUOpaEkgj4zozoGKyMSJLNcUxRFFC0IwDCUCwqAcNw-CaJkgl6PkmAqK05izTYsldVwMkuI8gt1wk+zpKIpzdJc3dKGUlsWLUwtNIc+MjN9UyB1jIcsFQlAwCVbUugETgCAAJXARhgHUTsFk7DY6zinBMwAQiXTiCrAThuMCyg4AwcQYBQFKCx-JALPa2VSuQGAKqq4QUzyK4rSiig2s4fjqxcFwVpNYT6ovIcrxvO8Hy2ozG1FIA). Requires `typescript>=3.9`. For best results, use `typescript>=4.3`

---

Previous answer:

Try this:

```
declare const is: {
    array<T, V>(val: T[] | V): val is T[]
}
```

Comment: I have tried this. But this occurs problems in other places. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73542395/accept-more-than-one-array-type-in-generic-typescript

Comment: @Vlad see the updated answer

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try it  in few hours) In any case, thank you)